# res.json is not a function - Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

The Next.js documentation was somewhat ambiguous and did not help with my issue -- I am having trouble with the getStaticPaths function. The following is the code I have:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    
    let res =  fetch("localhost:3000/api/main")
    const paths = res.json().map(state => ({
      params: {id: states.id},
    }))

    return {paths,
      fallback: false}
  }
```

Are there any thoughts as to why this doesn't work? I also have a getStaticProps functiom which does properly load res.json()

Comment: Hey, put http too: ```http://localhost:3000/api/main```, and you should await for fetch: ````const res = await fetch(url)````

Comment: `fetch` returns a pending promise, which doesn't have a `json()` method, so `res.json() is *clearly* not a function`. See Hadi's answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
  export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const res =  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/main")
    const decoded = await res.json();
    const paths = decoded.map(state => ({
      params: {state: states.id},
    }));
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false
    }
  }
```